# libgdx game, graphics are not displayed on ldpi screen

Tags: java, android, optimization, libgdx

I am loading all assets at the beginning of game play but on ldpi mobiles, after splash screen, it shows a white screen and I get the error egl swap memory buffer.
my code is as follows: in splash screen at constructor:

```
Assets.loadAssets();
```

in updateMethod

```
if(Assets.manager.update())    
{
    Assets.getLoadAssets();
    gameSplashObj.setScreen(new MainMenu(gameSplashObj));    
}
```

but I will get white screen. Am I doing something wrong or any other optimize way to achieve this.

Comment: `egl swap memory buffer` does not seem to be anything asset related. ldpi hints to be an old device. Do you use OpenGL 2? Maybe try to disable that in the startup configuration for Android.

Comment: yes it have problem in older device because some mdpi which are older than 2.3.6 has the same problem.

Comment: it has nothing to do with android version a hdpi phone with a better GPU on 2.3.5 will also run smotthly

Its all because of the texture size the phone can handle

Answer (score 2):

That usually happens (images as plain white) when the texture you are loading is bigger than the max texture size the device can handle (GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE).

If you plan on supporting ldpi devices, consider making your textures smaller.

Answer (score 1):

one easy way to solve this problem is While packing the image **

> set maximun width and height to 512 ,512 or even lower 256 ; instead
>   of 1024 or 2048.

** this way your graphics size will also not increase and on same time it solves problems with ldpi devices